# How to avoid an infinite loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have a Selenium `webdriverIO` V5 framework. The issue I am facing here is, the below code works fine on Mac OS, but it does not work correctly on the Windows OS. In the Windows OS it gets stuck with an infinite loop issue.

The below code functionality is: Merge `yaml` files (which contains locators) and return the value of the locator by passing the key:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const yamlMerge = require('yaml-merge');
const sleep = require('system-sleep');

let xpath;

class Page {
    getElements(elementId) {
        function objectCollector() {
            glob('tests/wdio/locators/*.yml', function (er, files) {
                if (er) throw er;
                xpath = yamlMerge.mergeFiles(files);
            });
            do {
                sleep(10);
            } while (xpath === undefined);
            return xpath;
        }

        objectCollector();
        return xpath[elementId];
    }
}

module.exports = new Page();
```

Comment: why would you even use nodejs if you don't want to use the benefit of asynchronous stuff, especially io related. Just don't use sleep or other blocking call.

Comment: The framework is nodeJS. So are you suggesting to remove sleep in 'do' section?

Comment: yes. avoid your dowhile loop and familiarize yourself with the asynchronous paradigm by either returning a promise from getElements or passing it a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are waiting on the results of a callback, I would recommend returning a new `Promise` from your `getElements` function and `resolve()` the value you receive inside the callback. Then when you call `getElements`, you will need to resolve that `Promise` or use the `await` notation. The function will stop at that point and wait until the `Promise` resolves, but the event loop will still continue. See some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for more information.

I'll write an example below of what your code might look like using a `Promise`, but when you call `getElements`, you will need to put the keyword `await` before it. If you want to avoid that, you could resolve the `Promise` from `objectCollector` while you're in `getElements` and remove the `async` keyword from its definition, but you really should not get in the way of asynchronous JavaScript. Also, you can probably shorten the code a bit because `objectCollector` looks like an unnecessary function in this example:

```
const glob = require('glob')
const yamlMerge = require('yaml-merge')
const sleep = require('system-sleep')

let xpath

class Page {
    function async getElements(elementId) {
        function objectCollector() {
            return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                glob('tests/wdio/locators/*.yml', function (er, files) {
                    if (er) reject(er)
                    resolve(yamlMerge.mergeFiles(files))
                })
            })
        }

        let xpath = await objectCollector()
        return xpath[elementId]
    }
}

module.exports = new Page();
```